# Checking INSERT in mysqli_multi_query() Procedural

Tags: php, mysql

I have a project file, and i have trouble at my syntax, example:

```
mysqli_query($connection,"START TRANSACTION");
$mysql_query = mysqli_multi_query($connection,"
    INSERT INTO `TABLE 1` (`ID`, `VAL`) VALUES (NULL, 'NAMBAH 1');
    INSERT INTO `TABLE 2` (`ID`, `VAL`) VALUES (NULL, 'NAMBAH 2');
    INSERT INTO `TABLE 3` (`ID`, `VAL`) VALUES (NULL, 'NAMBAH 3');
");
if(!$mysql_query){
    echo "Syntax MySQL: " . mysqli_error($connection);
}else{
    do{
    // Store first result set

    if ($result=mysqli_store_result($connection)){
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
  }while (mysqli_next_result($connection));
}
```

if imposible, i want to rollback if one MySQL Query is failed to inserted, i think we can check one by one for this query,

thanks for advance!.

Comment: `ID` is `NULL` , that's not correct approach

Comment: no problem at that, just i want to perfect to run my program and checking my query one by one

Comment: @AlivetoDie, It should be auto_increment.

Comment: Hahha, yes that it, that is A_I, thanks @Amir

Answer (score -1):

It should be something like this:

```
mysqli_autocommit($connection, FALSE);
$mysql_query = mysqli_multi_query($connection,"
    INSERT INTO `TABLE 1` (`ID`, `VAL`) VALUES (NULL, 'NAMBAH 1');
    INSERT INTO `TABLE 2` (`ID`, `VAL`) VALUES (NULL, 'NAMBAH 2');
    INSERT INTO `TABLE 3` (`ID`, `VAL`) VALUES (NULL, 'NAMBAH 3');
");
  do{
    // Store first result set

    if ($result=mysqli_store_result($connection)){
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
  }while (mysqli_next_result($connection));
  if( $mysqli_errno($connection)){
      $mysqli_commit($connection);
  }else{
      echo "MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($connection);
      $mysqli_rollback($connection);
  }
```